# Inherit the value from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created a animal class which holds the object of animal and its characteristics.

```
animal = function(){
    this.animalType = {
       tiger:{
         Character:[{
              Height: ,
              Color:'',
              Name:''
         }]
       },
       Lion:{
          Character:[{
             Height: ,
            Color:'',
            Name:''
       }]
       }
    };
};

  animal.prototype.getType = function(type){

  };
```

I want write a menthod  to get the Characteristics of the Animal
'type' holds the key for type of Animal

Comment: Your "animal class" seems way too complicated.

Comment: Do all tigers have the same height, colour and name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how your animal class should look like. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o4wuk4fm/)

```
var animal = function(o){
    this.type = o.type || 'unknown';
    this.height = o.height || -1;
    this.color = o.color || 'unknown';
    this.name = o.name || 'unknown';
}
animal.prototype.getType = function(){
    return this.type;
}

var tiger = new animal({
    type: 'tiger',
    height: 120,
    color: 'red',
    name: 'billy'
});

alert(tiger.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks Grimbode. Finally if I have multiple objects in the animal class, again I create one more Instance variable right?

Comment: @Rajan Here is an example in use: http://jsfiddle.net/o4wuk4fm/1/ -- mark this answer as right if this is what you were looking for. Cheers.